# Protractor completes before test is finished

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, async-await, protractor

I use Protractor on non-angular website. My Test finish before all the asynchronous code in application.FindFreeCancellationRate() is finished[image]

as you can see - "Finished" in 11.461, but some statements are still printing in console after test has finished.

```
it('should find a Free Cancelation rate',  application.FindFreeCancellationRate, 20000000000);

it('should finish the test', function () {
   console.log("THE END");
});
```

application.FindFreeCancellationRate code:

```
async(function () {

        console.log("starting the async test ");
        var hrefs = await(app.GetAllResults());

        console.log("OpenResults is starting start");

        for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
            (function (_i) {
                console.log("result " + i + " of " + hrefs.length);

                var resultFound = await(app.checkHotelResults(hrefs[i]));
                console.log("openResults - result found");

                console.log(resultFound);
                if (resultFound) {
                    console.log("result found = true");
                    return resultFound;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("continue");
                }
            })(i)

        }
        console.log("OpenResults finished");
        console.log("finishing the async test ");
        return;
    });
```

and the other 2 functions:

```
app.checkHotelResults = async(function (aUrl) {

        console.log("app.checkHotelResults getting url");
        await(browser.driver.get(aUrl).then(function () { console.log("Sucess - got url"); return true;}));


        console.log("finding room option");
        //get all room options
        var els = await(browser.driver.findElements(By.css(".roomOptionRadio")).then(function (els) {
            console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   found room options")
            return els;
        }));

        console.log("found room options");

        //for each room option
        await(app.checkResults(els));
        return false;

    });

    app.checkResults = async(function (els) {
        els.forEach(function (el) {

            await(browser.sleep(2000));

            console.log("opening rate");
            await(browser.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", el));
            await(el.click());                
        });
        console.log("finished checkResults")
        return false;
    });
```

why is it quitting before executing all the code?
Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I'm not aware of Jasmine or protractor being compatible with `async`/`await` are you using a tool like [jasmine-es6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-es6) to provide a compatibility layer?